# heroku timeout with npm request

Tags: node.js, heroku, cron, request

I have a job I'm running via node-cron, which uses request to get data from a website, parse the data and insert a new record into the database.  Although everything is working fine, it gets the data, (which is only 200 bytes or so), parses it, creates a record and saves it, I'm getting timeout errors, and so it tries again, and ends up running 5 times, once every 30 seconds, so I end up with 5 new records in the database.  It's not the cron job that is running, it's only running once.

This is how it's called:

```
new CronJob('00 03 15 * * *', function() {Parse.Cloud.run("download", {"type" : "mm"});console.log("running mm");}, null, true, 'America/Los_Angeles');
```

Here is the code:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("download", function(req, status) {
var date = new Date();
var drawDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0)
drawDate.setUTCHours(drawDate.getUTCHours() - 8);

var month = ("0" + (drawDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
var day = ("0" + drawDate.getDate()).slice(-2);

var type = req.params["type"];
//var URL = baseURL + type + "/" + drawDate.getFullYear() + "-" + month + "-" + day + ".html";
var URL = baseURL + type + "/" + drawDate.getFullYear() + "-" + "02" + "-" + "17" + ".html"

console.log("url is " + URL)

request.get(URL, function (error, resp, body) {
        if (!error && resp.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log("in request")

            var bodyString = body.toString('utf8', 0);
            var items = bodyString.split(";");

            var MyClass = Parse.Object.extend("Draw");
            var draw = new MyClass();
            draw.set("drawDate", drawDate);
            draw.set("type", type);

            // set some other fields...
            draw.save(null, { useMasterKey: true }).then(
                function(success) {
                    console.log("Saved draw for date:" + drawDate.toString());
                },
                function(error) {
                    console.log("Error " + error + "saving pb draw for date:" + drawDate.toString());
                }
            )
        }
     }
)
})
```

and here is the error message I'm getting:

```
at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/parse/functions/downloadLotteryDraw" host=poolcaptain.herokuapp.com request_id=98481059-9cc2-4f66-b624-390775b66283 fwd="54.211.8.255" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0
```

I have no clue why everything seems to be executing correctly, yet I'm getting these timeouts.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Your error doesn't look related to the cron job. What's the code look like for this route: `path="/parse/functions/downloadLotteryDraw"`

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I found it, thought I updated here, but I seem to have forgotten.  The request.get needs a resp.success() or resp.error() to end the request, otherwise it's hanging out waiting to finish.

Comment: That's what I was looking for, if you had properly ended the response. Glad you figure it out!

Comment: Thanks! The fun of a new paradigm and language!